# Show more images in Tensorboard - Tensorflow object detection

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, tensorboard

I am using [Tensorflow's object detection framework](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection). Training and evaluation jobs are going well, but in tensorboard I am only able to see 10 images for the evaluation job. Is there a way to increase this number to look at more images? I tried changing the config file:

```
eval_config: {
  num_examples: 1000
  max_evals: 50
}

eval_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "xxx/eval.record"
  }
  label_map_path: "xxx/label_map.pbtxt"
  shuffle: false
  num_readers: 1
}
```

I thought the `max_eval` parameter would change this but it doesn't.

This is the command i'm running for the evaluation job:

```
python ../models/research/object_detection/eval.py \
    --logtostderr \
    --pipeline_config_path=xxx/ssd.config \
    --checkpoint_dir="xxx/train/" \
    --eval_dir="xxx/eval"
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It should be the `num_visualizations` parameter in your `eval_config` (cf. `eval.proto` [code](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/abd504235f3c2eed891571d62f0a424e54a2dabc/research/object_detection/protos/eval.proto#L8)).

Answer (score 6):

Probably the easiest way is to add command line argument `--samples_per_plugin`

Full example

```
tensorboard --logdir . --samples_per_plugin=images=100
```

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/1012

Comment: It works for me on several servers. I use the following version of  `tensorboard==1.14.0`

Answer (score 2):

I've been able to get this to work in Tensorboard 1.11.0 by editing the object_detection/protos/eval.proto file, then re-running protoc (see the Tensorflow docs). For example, this line in eval.proto would enable 100 examples (instead of the default 10):

```
optional uint32 num_visualizations = 1 [default=100];
```

This probably has an impact on system memory, browser performance, eval performance, etc.. so use with caution.